# XCode 4 migration questions

Tags: iphone, macos, xcode4

Instead of creating separate questions for each, here's a list of XCode 4 related stuff that I just can't seem to figure out. I've read the migration guide and the XCode 4 user manual.

1. How can I view the build log in XCode 4?
2. How can I build a run a Release version of my product? I don't want to archive it or submit it to iTunes, and I don't want to give up the ability to build/run the Debug version. Is creating a new scheme my only option?
3. How do I build using the command line and the different 'schemes'? Previously, I used `xcodebuild -project foo.xcodeproj -target TargetName -configuration Release|Debug`. What's the XCode 4 equivalent? How does it work if I have multiple schemes for each mode (see prev bullet)?
4. Is it just me, or did everyone feel pretty stupid when they started using XCode 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The left hand pane that contains the file hierarchy is called the Navigator Pane.  The right most tab on the tab bar is the log navigator.  You'll find 'em there.  If you want to see the raw text, select all, copy, and paste into TextEdit (or your editor of choice).
2. Set up a new scheme that builds against the Release configuration.
3. `xcodebuild -h` is your friend.  Generally, xcodebuild works just like it did in Xcode 3.
4. Yes.   Then I got used to it, embraced it, and realized I'm about 8.27x more efficient with Xcode 4 than 3.

Comment: You can also just edit the current scheme to choose which build configuration is used when running or profiling.  This might be a bit easier for some people to do than create a whole new scheme (although I know that's part of why they are there).

Comment: See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/Orientation/Orientation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH5-SW4 if you're not sure where to find the log button.

Comment: *Edit Scheme* then *Duplicate Scheme*;  current scheme is copied.  Change the build/analyze/run stuff, done.